# Is is possible to have two BContext classes , one for Database first scaffolding and another .NETCORE

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Good morning.
Is is possible to have two two DBContext classes , one for Database first scaffolding and another one so that i can use jwt token based authentication as using ,Net Core for creating WebAPI. The Scaffolded DBContext doesnt allow to inherit "IdentityDbContext"  but "DbContext". Which gives me a challenge to configure the middleware for jwt bearer.  . Please advice

Comment: Why not. Lets say if you were doing this DB first and creating the EDMX. You will create 2 (one for each DB).

Comment: If you are passing JWTs down to your database layer, there is a serious lack of separation of concerns in your application.  You should keep authentication and authorization as close to the API layer as possible.